Livewire: how to run scripts again or not to "break" existing ones
My code
<main>
    <div class="top-wrapper-page">
        <div class="center-bl">
            <div class="simple-page">
                <h1 class="mb-20">Favorite</h1>
                <div class="catalog-album active">
                    <div class="category-filter">
                        <div class="left-select">
                            <div class="select-drop" wire:ignore>
                                <a href="#" class="head-select btn-border"><i
                                        class="ico-sort left-ico"></i><span>@if (request()->has('sort'))
                                            {{\App\Models\Estate::sortList()[request()->input('sort')]}}
                                        @else
                                            Recomended
                                        @endif</span></a>
                                <div class="body-select mobile-swipeBlock" ontouchstart="return false;">
                                    <div class="box-scroll-btn box-scroll-btn-style"></div>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach(\App\Models\Estate::sortList() as $key => $name)
                                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" wire:click="setSort('{{$key}}')">{{$name}}</a>
                                            </li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#filterCategory" class="main-filter-btn btn-border btn-change-modal">
                                <i class="ico-filter left-ico"></i>
                                <span>Filter</span>
                                <div class="active-filter"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="btn-border btn-show-on-map"><i
                                    class="ico-map left-ico"></i><span>On map</span></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-ico big change-show-product {{$view == 'list' ? '' : 'open'}}"><i
                                    class="ico-grid"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="catalog-page {{$view == 'list' ? 'list' : ''}}">
                        @foreach($estates as $item)
                            @if ($item->estate)
                                @include('inc.ad', ['item' => $item->estate])
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
 </main> 

When I do sorting for the first time - everything is fine. When I want to do it a second time - the drop-down menu does not work.
I tried reinitializing the scripts
$wire.on('favourite-page-filter', () => {});

But then wire:click does not work. Adding wire:ignore didn't help either
How can I reinitialize the scripts?
Update: add code from dropdown menu
$('.select-drop .head-select').on('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            let $parent = $(this).closest('.select-drop')
                            $parent.toggleClass('open')
                        });
                        $('.select-drop .body-select a').on('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            let $parent = $(this).closest('.select-drop')
                            $parent.find('.head-select span').html($(this).text())
                            $(this).closest('.select-drop').find('.body-select li a').removeClass('active')
                            $(this).addClass('active')
                            $parent.removeClass('open')
                            $('body').removeClass('drop-open-mobile')
                        });

